# Make a dictionary consisting of index of words in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input: a list of strings as `['who are they','are you there?','Yes! you be there']`

Output: a dictionary that maps each word in any string to the set consisting of the
            ids for all strings containing the word.

```
output = {'who':[1], 'are':[1,2], 'they':[1], 'you':[2,3], 'there':[2], 'Yes':[3], 'be':[3]}
```

I am stuck please help, i am unable to make a method or procedure that performs this function.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object to gather your ids, and `enumerate()` to generate them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)

for index, sentence in enumerate(inputlist):
    for word in sentence.lower().split():
         output[word.strip('!?. ')].append(index)
```

Note that I lowercase the sentence and strip any leftover punctuation.

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'are': [0, 1], 'they': [0], 'be': [2], 'who': [0], 'yes': [2], 'there': [1, 2], 'you': [1, 2]})
```

This uses 0-based indexing (like everything in Python). If you *have* to count from 1, tell `enumerate()` to start counting from there:

```
for index, sentence in enumerate(inputlist, 1):
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem like this:

```
def toDict(l):
    ids, output,i = {}, {},1
    for sentence in l:
        ids[sentence] = i
        i += 1
    for sentence in l:
        words = sentence.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in output:
                output[word].append(ids[sentence])
            else:
                output[word] = []
                output[word].append(ids[sentence])
    return output
```

which returns:

```
 {'be': [3], 'there': [3], 'who': [1], 'Yes!': [3], 'there?': [2], 'are': [1, 2], 'they': [1], 'you': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this fun solution:

```
import string
a = ['who are they','are you there?','Yes! you be there']
x ={}
for word in ' '.join(a).translate(None,string.punctuation).lower().split():
    try:x[word]+=1
    except:x[word]=1
print x
```

- join() the list of strings to form a string, since you don't care how the words are organized
- translate() to remove punctuations
- lower() all characters to lower case so you don't treat "Yes" and "yes" differently
- split() the string into words
- try, except and code-golf your way around the longer if statement